# SKShapeNode fillTexture sometimes not working with Swift

Tags: swift, ios8, sprite-kit

I'm trying to fill a simple `SKShapeNode` square specified via points with a texture. It's supposed to be pretty simple, since you can now set the `.fillTexture` attribute to an `SKTexture` of your choosing.

However, I had really inconsistent results, with a brief period of grace where the texture would actually show. Then I would try to change to another texture and the new texture wouldn't show. It seems like the size of the square may also influence whether the texture shows or not...?

> **GameScene.swift**

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        // Set background
        let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
        background.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        background.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        addChild(background)

        // Record scene size
        let w = self.size.width
        let h = self.size.height

        // Screen center
        let center = CGPoint(x: w/2, y: h/2)

        // Make points
        let squarePoints = UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>.alloc(5)
        squarePoints[0] = CGPoint(x: -40, y: -40)
        squarePoints[1] = CGPoint(x:  40, y: -40)
        squarePoints[2] = CGPoint(x:  40, y:  40)
        squarePoints[3] = CGPoint(x: -40, y:  40)
        squarePoints[4] = CGPoint(x: -40, y: -40)


        // Make the SKShapeNode
        var square = SKShapeNode(points: squarePoints, count: 5)
        square.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        square.lineWidth = 2.0
        square.position = center
        square.fillTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "square")
        addChild(square)

        // Define an action
        var action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(-1.0, duration: 1.0)
        square.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))

        //
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

> **GameViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
        let skView = view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true
        scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
        skView.presentScene(scene)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

I really have nothing else in the code. The result is a rotating empty white square with no fill on top of the background image. I'd post a screenshot, but I can't yet.

Comment: I've found that fillTexture doesn't work as expected without setting the node's fillColor to an opaque white.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried leaving off the last point and seeing if it will connect to the origin automatically?

Comment: I tried, and it doesn't. If I fill the shape with a color, the fill area completes, but the stroke like does not.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
SKTexture(imageNamed: "square.png")
```

or whatever image type you are using